# Resumed a Download Using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

i am downloading a file from the web. When i resumed the downloading of the file, it restart again from the starting point and not from the point where i have paused the download. i have saved the values of the downloading file at the point i paused the download. but now i am unable how to resumed the download of the file where i have paused.
I am using this code for downloading a new file

```
      url = [NSURL URLWithString:_item.link];   
    _receivedBytes = 0;
    _speed = 0;
    _lastTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    _connection = [ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_connection setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];
    [_connection setDelegate: self];
    [_connection setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
    [_connection setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
    [_connection setDownloadDestinationPath: _item.path];
    [_connection startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the ASIHTTPRequest docs resuming interrupted downloads works only if you are downloading directly into a file.

I assume that you download into memory (because you are using `_receivedBytes`).

If you are storing the downloaded file into the devices filesystem anyway, you could download it directly into the filesystem by using:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:@"/path/to/tempfolder/yourfile.jpg.download"];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/path/to/final/destination/yourfile.jpg"];
```

Then you can enable the resuming of interrupted downloads by setting:

```
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
```

You'll find more details [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: i have changed it ASIHTTPRequest, but when i resumed the download, the progress view again start from the zero bytes.

Comment: Have you implemented it as described in the ASIHTTPRequest documentation under "Resuming interrupted downloads"?

Comment: so you are setting both a temp path and a destination path? (I forgot the destination path, see my edited answer)

Comment: DLDownload *resumedDownload = [[DLDatabase sharedDatabase] getDownloadValues:_item.link];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:resumedDownload.link];
_receivedBytes = resumedDownload.currentOffset;
_connection = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_connection setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];

Comment: [_connection setDelegate: self];
[_connection setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
[_connection setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[_connection setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:resumedDownload.tempPath];
[_connection setDownloadDestinationPath: resumedDownload.path];
[_connection startAsynchronous];

Comment: Are you still storing the downloaded bytes in _receivedBytes? That won't work. You have to download it directly into the file system. Resuming a download won't work with ASIDownloadCache.

Comment: now the resuming functionality is working, but the file does not work after the point i have resumed.